# Resque does not honor application config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, config, resque

I Have been using resque quite comfortably, But for following scenario

In one of my perform method

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.perform
    B.something
  end
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.something
   l = Misc.get_locale
    ....
    ....
  end
end

class Misc
  def self.get_locale
    return I18n.locale
  end
end
```

Issue is that it always return I18n.locale as **:en** even though in my application config, I have set it to **:us_en**(or whatever), like below

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :us_en
config.i18n.locale = :us_en
```

Is it because I am reading that I18n.locale from a class and not a rails Model?
Or is it because of some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more likely that resque isn't reading your rails configuration.

You can try setting this in an initializer (which I believe should get read).

`config/initalizers/i18n.rb` :

```
I18n.default_locale = 'en-US'
I18n.locale = 'en-US'
```

As a side note, the language code comes first before the region code in the [bcp47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) standard for identifying languages (just me being anal though!).

Comment: cool. i will try this. and about that language code I will try follow standards.